# manager.requestImageForAssetのimageがnilになってしまう

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

前提・実現したいこと

swiftで日記アプリを作っています。 
実現したいことは、ユーザーのライブラリから写真データを取得して一覧表示し、写真選択機能を作成することです。

発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

ライブラリから取得した写真データのアセットをmanager.requestImageForAssetでuiimageにしたいのですが、nilになってしまいます。

```
let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode.HighQualityFormat
        options.synchronous = true
        options.networkAccessAllowed = true

        let asset = appDelegate?.photosAssets[indexPath.row-1]
        print("イメージ1\(appDelegate?.photosAssets)")
        let manager:PHImageManager = PHImageManager()
        manager.requestImageForAsset(asset!, targetSize: CGSizeMake((self.view.bounds.size.width-4)/3, (self.view.bounds.size.height-4)/3), contentMode: PHImageContentMode.AspectFill, options: options, resultHandler:{(image,info)->Void in
               print("イメージ\(image)")
               print("info\(info)")

            if image != nil{

                cell.imageView.image = image
            }
        })
```

infoを確認すると、uiimageの生成がうまくいった時は、

```
infoOptional([PHImageResultIsDegradedKey: 0, PHImageResultWantedImageFormatKey: 5003, PHImageFileOrientationKey: 0, PHImageResultDeliveredImageFormatKey: 5003])
```

uiimageがnilになる時は、以下のようになります。

```
infoOptional([PHImageResultIsDegradedKey: 0, PHImageResultWantedImageFormatKey: 5003, PHImageResultIsPlaceholderKey: 0, PHImageResultIsInCloudKey: 0, PHImageResultDeliveredImageFormatKey: 0])
```

や、

```
([PHImageResultDeliveredImageFormatKey: 5003, PHImageResultIsDegradedKey: 0, PHImageResultWantedImageFormatKey: 5003])
```

どのようにすれば、解決できますでしょうか。 
よろしくお願いします。

補足
他サイトでも質問させていただきましたが、解決に至っていない状況なので、質問させていただきます。
https://teratail.com/questions/31278?complete=

Comment: あなたのコードでは`options.synchronous = true`を設定していますから、バックグラウンドスレッドでしか実行してはいけないコードになっています。確実にバックグランドスレッドでしか実行されないように制御しているでしょうか。それだけが原因かどうかはわかりませんが、まずは`options.synchronous = true`を削除(または`false`に設定)してどのような挙動になるか調べてみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。
options.synchronous = trueを削除してみたのですが、状況は変わりませんでした。

Comment: また、同じコードにもかかわらず、シュミレーターでiPad2では問題なく写真が表示されるのですが、iPadProなど他のものではnilになります。
一度シュミレーターをリセットしても、iPad2では問題なく、iPadProなど他のものではnilになります。もし何かお分かりでしたら、返信いただけると助かります。

Comment: 「非同期処理の使い方の誤りではない」ことがわかっただけで、すぐに解決につながるような情報にはなりえなかったようですね。Appleの[サンプルコード](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014575)でも`if image == nil {return}`に相当するコード(元コードでは`image`ではなく`result`)がresultHandler内に記述されている部分があるのですが、どのような条件で発生し、どう対処すべきものなのかを記載したドキュメントは見つけられませんでした。手元のサンプルコードでは決してnilにならないので、確認できません。ご記載いただいたiPad Pro等でも試してみて、何か分かりましたらコメントさせていただきます。

Comment: お手数おかけします。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 残念ながら少しの時間コードをいじっていてもAppleのsample codeでは`result`が`nil`になるケースは(実機でもsimulatorでも)ありませんでした。Appleのsample codeとあなたのコードとの違いで気になるのは【`cell.imageView`に埋めるための画像取得ではサムネイルサイズを指定し、`PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode.HighQualityFormat`は指定しない】(高解像度の画像が必要な場合には、再度requestImageForAssetを呼んでいる)と言ったあたりでしょうか。[Swift版サンプルコード](https://github.com/ooper-shlab/SamplePhotosApp-Swift)と見比べながら試していただければと思います。iCloudが関わると挙動が変わるという記事もあったので、そこら辺の条件が絞り込めるなら、その情報もご記載ください。

Comment: options.PHImageReques‌​tOptionsDeliveryMode.HighQualityFormatをコメントアウトしたところ、正常に写真を表示できました！ここが原因だったようです。本当にありがとうございます。

普段の実機テストでは問題なく、久しぶりにシュミレーターでテストしたところ今回の状態になったので、シュミレーターの処理速度などの問題でHighQualityFormatだとimageがnilになっていたと考えるのが自然でしょうか。
HighQualityFormatをコメントアウトすると写真がぼやけてしまうので、シュミレーターの問題であれば、本番環境ではPHImageReques‌​tOptionsDeliveryMode.HighQualityFormatを指定するという考え方で問題ないのでしょうか。

Comment: 実はAppleのsample codeの側をあなたのコードに合わせて修正しても(`HighQualityFormat`もそのまま)、nil状態を再現できなかったので、確実なことが言えない状態です。ただ、「自分の場合には」と言う限定付きでも、多くの開発者にとって有用な情報だと思われるので、できれば時間をとってご自身の解決策を「回答」として書き込んでみてください。実アプリとしては、CollectionViewやTableView内に表示するイメージには`HighQualityFormat`は指定せず、ユーザが実際に選択した後で必要な部分だけ`HighQualityFormat`で中身を取り直す、と言うのが正解な気がします。(他に何かあればまた「回答」へのコメントで。)

Comment: 了解しました。今夜中に回答を書きこみます。
ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

今回の質問の現象は、iosのシュミレーターにのみ生じており、またシュミレーターの中でも問題なく写真表示できるものもあったりとよくわからないのが現状ですが、現時点での修正を書きます。

修正
PHImageReques‌​tOp‌​tionsDeliveryMode.HighQualityFormatを設定していたのを削除しました。
その結果、どのシュミレーターでもimageがnilにならないようになりました。

自分の環境では、なぜか写真がところどころぼやけてしまう（スクロールするとくっくりとなる）という問題はありますが、それはそれで修正していきたいと思います。

レアなケースかもしれませんが情報がお役に立ててばと思います。